# How to communicate php between javascript?

Tags: html

How can i get the html table rows , then by clicking the button it will show the values in another page. in short i want to hold this variables in session to be use in other purposes.

Comment: You can use `php`'s [`session`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned sessions, you can use [`sessions`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm).

Here is an example *(without using table rows, but you get the idea)*:

**page1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['someName'] = 'someDate';
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['someName'])){
        echo $_SESSION['someName']; //outputs someDate
    }
?>
```

**page2-js.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['someName'])){
        echo '<script>alert("'.$_SESSION['someName'].'")</script>'; //outputs someDate
    }
?>
```